# Android app prevent app killing by auto task killer

Tags: android

Is there a way to set some priority to the app, so Task killer can't kill it?
I don't want to add my app to task killer safe list.
I want to my app be invisible to task killer.

Is that possible?

Comment: This wasn't my question. I don't want my app to auto-restart. But as far as I know it can be done. At least on force close...I've done that...that after crash...app start again it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no one "App killer". There **are** apps that act like that, so each user can have different one (wise users do not have any ;) and I do not expect apps like that to allow other apps to auto-add themselves on their whitelist. My suggestion is just ignore this and educate your users that app killers shall be avoided and can cause more harm than benefits. Android can handle own resources quite well and hopefuly there will be no like "task killer" type of app around as Android disallows other apps to mess with tasks since (afair) HC

Comment: Ok, I thought so, just wanned to check it out, just in case :) Tnx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As lenik points out, the mobile device belongs to the user, and it is the user - and the user only - who decides what software does or does not run on the device. Any app trying to do what you seem to want yours to do would be considered very dubious by security-conscious users. It doesn't matter that you may have good reasons for the app to do this - what matters is how such abilities can be misused.

Don't underestimate the intelligence of your users.

Simply inform your users to not use Task Killer at some appropriate point in the software (or the in-app help/online manual), and you will have handled the issue for 99.999% of your users.