# My Android APP is treated unfairly by some third-party task killers in China: how can we avoid it?

Tags: android

the third-party task killers lure users to root their mobiles and then control users' mobiles. Since they gain the root rights, they use default settings to prevent our app auto start and kill our app by "clean memory". Apps of Big companies can be set default to auto start and be put in the "white list" of task killing, but for small companies, their APPs will be set as not permit to auto start and will be killed now and then by them, such as 360.   It's a tragedy especially for small companies' APPs which must stay online.

My question is:how can our APPs avoid the destine tortured by the third-party task killers in China? can  we protect our APPs from killed by them?  We accept the system task killer of android.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android app prevent app killing by auto task killer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527420/android-app-prevent-app-killing-by-auto-task-killer)

Comment: I have read this question and answers, and totally agree to @Michael A. said"As lenik points out, the mobile device belongs to the user, and it is the user - and the user only - who decides what software does or does not run on the device. Any app trying to do what you seem to want yours to do would be considered very dubious by security-conscious users."—---The situation in China is that all the task killers are trying to lure users to root mobiles, then they will control users' mobiles and it's task killers ,not users,who decide the default of what app should be killed or be set auto start

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski's solution:"My suggestion is just ignore this and educate your users that app killers shall be avoided and can cause more harm than benefits"----in China, There indeed have "App killer"! and we small developers are treated unfairly by them. they are controlling the market and cheating users to believe them useful, it's hard to educate users to leave them